# Option for allowing new users to post to a Phpbb version 3 forum

Tags: users, configuration, phpbb

I am trying to allow new users to post to the forum.  It is not showing me the option of turning this off or on in the settings.

Comment: Since you haven't had an answer, I suggest hitting the phpBB forums